# How to eliminate flicker in Windows.Forms custom control when scrolling?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, gdi+

I want to create a custom control in C#. But every time I have to fully redraw my control, it flickers, even if I use double buffering (drawing to an Image first, and blitting that).

How do I eliminate flicker when I have to fully redraw?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could try putting the following in your constructor after the InitiliseComponent call.

```
SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer | 
         ControlStyles.UserPaint |
         ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);
```

EDIT:

If you're giving this a go, if you can, remove your own double buffering code and just have the control draw itself in response to the appropriate virtual methods being called.

Comment: I usually put that stuff in before the Application.Run, but yea this I think is the best solution to this problem.

Comment: I agree. I've also found a good url in another flicker-related question.
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/DoubleBuffering.aspx

Comment: I've tried soooo mant different solutions but this fixes it!! +1 for telling to put it after InitializeComponent(); !! xoxoxo

Answer (score 8):

I pulled this from a working C# program.  Other posters have syntax errors and clearly copied from C++ instead of C#

```
SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer | 
                        ControlStyles.UserPaint |
                        ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);
```

Answer (score 1):

It may be good enough to just call

```
SetStyle(ControlStyles::UserPaint | ControlStyles::AllDrawingInWmPaint, true);
```

The flickering you are seeing most likely because Windows draws the background of the control first (via WM_ERASEBKGND), then asks your control to do whatever drawing you need to do (via WM_PAINT).  By disabling the background paint and doing all painting in your OnPaint override can eliminate the problem in 99% of the cases without the need to use all the memory needed for double buffering.

Answer (score 0):

You say you've tried double buffering, but then you say drawing to an Image first and blitting that. Have you tried setting DoubleBuffered = true in the constructor rather than doing it yourself with an Image?