# How do I disable updating a form in Windows Forms?

Tags: .net, winforms

During a complicated update I might prefer to display all the changes at once. I know there is a method that allows me to do this, but what is it?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I think this.SuspendLayout() & ResumeLayout() should do it

Answer (score 20):

I don't find `SuspendLayout()` and `ResumeLayout()` do what you are asking for.
`LockWindowsUpdate()` [mentioned by moobaa](https://stackoverflow.com/a/126914/7444103) does the trick. However,  `LockWindowUpdate` only works for one window at a time.

You can also try this:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.Win32;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 wMsg, bool wParam, Int32 lParam);
    private const int WM_SETREDRAW = 11; 

    public Form1()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      SendMessage(this.Handle, WM_SETREDRAW, false, 0);

      // Do your thingies here
      SendMessage(this.Handle, WM_SETREDRAW, true, 0);

      this.Refresh();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use the old [Win32](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_API) [LockWindowUpdate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145034(v=vs.85).aspx) function:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern long LockWindowUpdate(long Handle);

try {
    // Lock Window...
    LockWindowUpdate(frm.Handle);
    // Perform your painting / updates...
} 
finally {
    // Release the lock...
    LockWindowUpdate(0);
}
```

Comment: Try this syntax instead:
private static extern long LockWindowUpdate(IntPtr Handle);
and
 LockWindowUpdate(IntPtr.Zero);

Comment: LockWindowUpdate is not designed or intended to stop flickering. You should be using `SetWindowRedraw(hwnd, false)`. (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/06/10/152612.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

Most complex third-party Windows Forms components have `BeginUpdate` and `EndUpdate` methods or similar, to perform a batch of updates and *then* drawing the control. At the form level, there is no such a thing, but you could be interested by enabling [Double buffering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64272/how-to-eliminate-flicker-in-windowsforms-custom-control-when-scrolling).

Answer (score 1):

You can use SuspendLayout and ResumeLayout methods in the form or controls while updating properties. If you're binding data to controls you can use BeginUpdate and EndUpdate methods.

Comment: BeginUpdate and EndUpdate methods on which? A form does not have them.

Answer (score 0):

SuspendLayout will help performance if the updates involve changes to controls and layout:
[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.suspendlayout.aspx)