# Defer form updates

Tags: c#, winforms

Is there a way to defer a form from updating/repainting while manipulating controls?

I am using the `TableLayoutPanel` control on my form, and I want to remove/add different user controls into different cells of the table dynamically at runtime.

When I do this, the screen update is too slow, and there is some blinking action happening.

```
tablelayout.SuspendLayout()
```

`SuspendLayout()` seems to have no effect.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/126876/how-do-i-disable-updating-a-form-in-winforms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I completely got rid of the flicker by creating a class that inherited the table, then enabled doublebuffering.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace myNameSpace.Forms.UserControls
{
    public class TableLayoutPanelNoFlicker : TableLayoutPanel
    {
        public TableLayoutPanelNoFlicker()
        {
            this.DoubleBuffered = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the control; look for `BeginUpdate` / `EndUpdate` or `BeginEdit` / `EndEdit`, etc (and use them in a `try`/`finally` block). Note, however, that only *some* controls have these methods, and they aren't bound to a handy interface so it is a bit manual. For example:

```
    listView.BeginUpdate();
    try
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            listView.Items.Add("Item " + i);
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        listView.EndUpdate();
    }
```

Note that data-bound controls may have other mechanisms for disabling data-related changes; for example, `BindingList<T>` has a settable `RaiseListChangedEvents` that turns off change-notifications while you edit data. You might also look at things like "virtual mode".

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
try {
    SuspendLayout();

    // manipulate your controls

} finally {
    ResumeLayout();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try SuspendLayout / ResumeLayout - this is how the code generated by the forms designer does it - take a look inside the InitializeComponents method in the code behind for a form to see what I mean.