# Win32 GUI flickering on resize

Tags: user-interface, winapi, resize, flicker

I have a Win32 GUI program with a tab control, each tab having a list view control. There is massive flickering whenever the window is resized. I've tried the following things:

- Handling WM_ERASEBKGND in the main wndproc and returning TRUE. No effect.
- Filtering out all WM_ERASEBKGND messages in the event loop. No effect.
- Setting the WM_CLIPCHILDREN style on the main window. Now when the window is resized the list view control is simply erased to a white background and doesn't redraw.
- Using DefWindowPos instead of MoveWindow. No effect.
- Passing FALSE for bRepaint in MoveWindow. Same effect as setting WS_CLIPCHILDREN (see above).

Here's the RegisterClassEx code:

```
memset(&wcex, 0, sizeof(WNDCLASSEX));
wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
wcex.style = 0;
wcex.lpfnWndProc = PhMainWndProc;
wcex.cbClsExtra = 0;
wcex.cbWndExtra = 0;
wcex.hInstance = PhInstanceHandle;
wcex.hIcon = LoadIcon(PhInstanceHandle, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_PROCESSHACKER));
wcex.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
//wcex.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1);
wcex.lpszMenuName = MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDR_MAINWND);
wcex.lpszClassName = PhWindowClassName;
wcex.hIconSm = (HICON)LoadImage(PhInstanceHandle, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_PROCESSHACKER), IMAGE_ICON, 16, 16, 0);
```

The WM_SIZE handler:

```
RECT rect;

// Resize the tab control.

GetClientRect(PhMainWndHandle, &rect);
MoveWindow(TabControlHandle, rect.left, rect.top,
    rect.right - rect.left, rect.bottom - rect.top, TRUE);

// Resize the list view.

TabCtrl_AdjustRect(TabControlHandle, FALSE, &rect);

MoveWindow(ListViewHandle, rect.left, rect.top,
    rect.right - rect.left, rect.bottom - rect.top, TRUE);
```

The styles are as follows:

- Main window: `WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW`
- Tab control: `WS_CHILD` (and `WS_VISIBLE`)
- List view control: `WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER | LVS_REPORT` (and `WS_VISIBLE`)

Comment: Ah yes, win32 window flickering. This brings back memories...

Comment: I wonder if double buffering would help somehow...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turned out there was a problem with the Z-ordering - calling BringWindowToTop on the list view solved the problem.

Comment: I had the same problem. Calling `BringWindowToTop` for window shown as tab's contents solved it. I have done it in InitDialog after showing the initial tab and each time selected tab changed after showing new tab.

Comment: I also had similar problems with flickering (on resizing) tabs control itself. This was solved by adding `WS_CLIPCHILDREN` style to parent dialog.

Comment: Thanks for this, had the same problem and calling BringWindowToTop solved it

Answer (score 2):

Windows supports a re-size batching operation that is meant to avoid flicker caused when lots of child windows are indepently resized. See [BeginDeferWindowPos](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632672(VS.85).aspx) for more information on that.

If that is not working, then try the [WM_SETREDRAW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145219(VS.85).aspx) message. It looks possible to stop drawing of the parent window - which will inhibit all the child controls, then, when the layout is finished, enable drawing again, and call RedrawWindow to repaint the entire window in one pass. I did rather think that this is what Defered window positioning would use internally.

Answer (score 1):

I may be stating the obvious, but I thought **[double buffering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_buffering#Double_buffering_in_computer_graphics)** is the solution to Win32 flickers. I'm a Java Developer and it has been a while sine I wrote win32 so please let me know if I'm talking nonsense

Here is the how to: http://www.gamedev.net/community/forums/topic.asp?topic_id=411559

Here is some sampe code: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/DoubleBuffering.aspx

Here is the .NET equivalent question (?): [How to prevent a Windows Forms TextBox from flickering on resize?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1333393/how-to-prevent-a-windows-forms-textbox-from-flickering-on-resize)

Comment: I set the LVS_EX_DOUBLEBUFFER extended style on the list view already. Or are you talking about another kind of double buffering? FYI I tried using WS_EX_COMPOSITED but as with WS_CLIPCHILDREN the list view doesn't redraw anymore :(

Answer (score 0):

> When a  ListView is Docked, as in
>   Windows Explorer (and you have a good
>   amount of items), resizing the main
>   form will cause all of the items to
>   flicker. 
>   http://www.codeproject.com/KB/list/listviewxp.aspx

Comment: I'm not using .NET, so it is not "docked".

Comment: Even if the article talks about .net the problem is a win32 generic trouble and all of us who have done anything using win32api gui-controls have more or less hit the listview flicker problem when doing anything that isn't toy code.

Comment: Could you suggest how the article would apply to my situation? I've already tried filtering out all erase background messages, so that can't be the problem :(

Comment: Have you isolated the trouble as a listview trouble? the tabcontrols have there own way of messing things up. Maybe  you have just missed some call that forces something to update.

Comment: Do you expect me to know what functions to use? ;) I'm a fairly experienced developer, but I have 0 experience with Win32 GUIs.