# Controls Moving problem in Perl Win32::GUI

Tags: windows, perl

In Perl Win32::GUI desktop apps,
While checkbox checked status I need to hide some controls and I need to move the controls to places which are hidden, for window compact view in Perl Win32::GUI. While using below code the control's images are repeated(duplicates) at the time of Controls movement. Kindly please give solution to avoid duplicate images of controls while moving and resizing the window.

```
sub Check_Status{
  if($btwdates->GetCheck eq 1){
    $Pushlistmodelabel->Move(30,168);
    $Fromdatelabel->Show();
    $get_From_day->Show();
    $Todatelabel->Show();
    $get_To_day->Show();
    $FoldersOption->Disable();


    $PushListButton->Move(200,255);
    $processlabel->Move(2,285);

    $PushListButton->Move(135,295);
    $processlabel->Move(2,320);


    $Selectionlabel->Move(195,168);
    $FilesOption->Move(200,195);
    $FoldersOption->Move(200,225);

    $With_root->Move(35,195);
    $Without_root->Move(35,225);
    $changeOption->Move(35,255);
    $replacepath->Move(180,255);
    Win32::GUI::DoEvents() >= 0;

  }
  else{
    $FoldersOption->Move(200,165);
    $FilesOption->Move(200,135);
    $FoldersOption->Enable();
    $Selectionlabel->Move(195,108);
    $Pushlistmodelabel->Move(30,108);

    $Fromdatelabel->Hide();
    $get_From_day->Hide();
    $Todatelabel->Hide();
    $get_To_day->Hide();


    $PushListButton->Move(200,195);
    $processlabel->Move(2,225);
    $Pushlistmodelabel->Move(30,108);
    $With_root->Move(35,135);
    $Without_root->Move(35,165);
    $changeOption->Move(35,195);
    $replacepath->Move(180,195);

  }
}
```

Comment: Please [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/5594550/edit) and complete the problem description, it is cut off in the middle of a sentence. Add your code so that interested people can reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking a shot in the dark (I don't have a win32 perl install), you could try the [`SetRedraw` method](http://perl-win32-gui.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/docs.cgi?doc=reference-methods#setredraw). `SetRedraw(0)` before rearranging the controls and `SetRedraw(1)` afterwards. Maybe also a manual `Redraw()` afterwards.

There is a non-perl-specific discussion of some techniques for avoiding flicker when updating a window in the question [Win32 GUI flickering on resize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2036599/win32-gui-flickering-on-resize).

Comment: Great!!! Thanks for your solution. Redrawing window is working for my application.