# Is it possible to set the MinimumSize property of another process' form? C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I want **my program** to make the **main form of another process** have a minimum window size.

I have the correct window handle and tried setting the size of the window if it is smaller than my wanted size,
but this way it is totally flashing.

**MoveWindow()** makes it flash too much,
**SetWindowPos()** aswell

---

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows.Forms;


namespace myProgram
{
  public partial class Form1 : Form
  {
    public Form1()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      foreach (var process in Process.GetProcessesByName("myTarget"))
      {
        var handle = process.MainWindowHandle; // gets all instances of the target game
        // Something like SetWindowProperty(handle, MinimumSize, new Size(500, 500)) would be perfect
        // or: setting the size with
          // MoveWindow() - flashes horribly
          // SetWindowPos() - flashes horribly aswell
          // something else?
      }
    }
  }
}
```

---

I would like a solution which is smoother and doesn't flash or look horrible.

The target program is a game, with a sizeable windows form.

Comment: it seems that your question is not clear to me. do you have any sample where i can refer what you need?

Comment: you may need to implement global system hook, intercept and modify `lParam` in `WM_GETMINMAXINFO`. I don't think this is possible in C# alone.

Comment: please see this [Win32 GUI flickering on resize](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2036599/win32-gui-flickering-on-resize) question.<br/>

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [MoveWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633534(v=vs.85).aspx). Which looks like:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
internal static extern bool MoveWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int X, int Y, int nWidth, int nHeight, bool rePaint);
```

Where hWnd is the application you want to resize.

Comment: Using this will make my target flash, which is what I don't want.