# Double-buffering *framework* in C and Windows GDI

Tags: c, windows, winapi, gdi+, gdi

**Background**: My client has a very extensive proprietary forms library which is effectively implemented in C (actually, it's a proprietary object-oriented language that basically wraps Windows controls and interacts with them with `SendMessage()`, `SetStyle()`, etc.)

**Problem I want to solve**: Whenever I drag/resize a top-level window (or drag a splitter) in an app implemented in the above framework, there is massive flicker. The top-level window is repainted, and any controls it contains repaint themselves.

**Question 1**: Is there a way to surgically introduce double-buffering into the forms library. In particular, I want to know if I can implement double-buffering using standard Windows GDI functions.

For *example*, if I could cause the top-level windows to be double-buffered such that all child windows of the top-level window are automatically drawn double-buffered as well. An even better alternative would be to be able to introduce double-buffering on any arbitrary window and have all its children inherit this.

The best solution would somehow cause the `BeginPaint()` function for child controls to return a handle to the DC of the offscreen back buffer so that I don't have to write special code for each individual control class.

**Question 2**: Is there a way (such as a set of flags) to cause generic Windows controls (EDIT, BUTTON, and so on) to draw themselves double-buffered? This would be a worse solution than a more generic approach that would just seamlessly give them the back buffer to draw on, but it might also be acceptable.

All help greatly appreciated. Please let me know if I can clarify anything for you.

Answer (score 3):

Look into [WS_EX_COMPOSITED](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff700543%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which is an extended window style that turns on double-buffering for the window.  It may be enough to set this style on the parent of the controls.

Comment: I will definitely look into this -- it may be exactly that I need. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks a lot. WS_EX_COMPOSITED worked for child windows. But I also had to use WS_CLIPSIBLINGS|WS_CLIPCHILDREN for popup windows (windows with style WS_POPUP) to avoid flickering. Note that the above are not extended styles but regular styles.

Answer (score 0):

You actually might be able to wrap all your window drawing code with C that executes C#, and that way there is already a double-buffered implementation for you.

[How to eliminate flicker in Windows.Forms custom control when scrolling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64272/how-to-eliminate-flicker-in-windows-forms-custom-control-when-scrolling)